# Error when i'm running my compiled JavaScript code with node

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, node-modules

I'm trying to compile my typescript code into commonjs to use it with node. But i'm getting this error after running node `dist/server/src/index.js` :

```
Server listening at http://localhost:3002
Error: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at /home/maxime/Dev/JeuxDuPlacard/packages/server/dist/server/src/index.js:10:55
    at /home/maxime/Dev/JeuxDuPlacard/packages/server/dist/server/src/technical/typeorm/connexion.js:60:21
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
```

I don't understand why this error shows up because i dont see any `import` statement inside my compiled js files.

for exemple here is `dist/server/index.js` :

```
var __importDefault = (this && this.__importDefault) || function (mod) {
    return (mod && mod.__esModule) ? mod : { "default": mod };
};
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
require("reflect-metadata");
var connexion_1 = require("./technical/typeorm/connexion");
var app_1 = __importDefault(require("./app"));
var port = 3002;
connexion_1.createConnection(function (error) { throw new Error(error.message); })
    .catch(function (error) { return console.log(error); });
app_1.default.listen(port, function () { return console.log("Server listening at http://localhost:" + port); });
//# sourceMappingURL=index.js.map
```

I do not want to use the top-level field `{ "type"="module" }` in my package.json file, because i would like to use the `import` syntax only in my dev environment (with typescript) and keep the regular commonjs module resolution for running my app with node.

I'm using node `14.15.4`

what i'm doing wrong ?

my **package.json** file

```
   "name": "server",
   "version": "1.0.0",
   "main": "index.js",
   "license": "MIT",
   "private": true,
   "type": "commonjs",
   "scripts": {
      "test": "echo testing server",
      "start": "tsc --watch",
      "build": "tsc"
   },
   "dependencies": {
      "@types/cors": "^2.8.9",
      "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.0",
      "bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
      "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
      "cors": "^2.8.5",
      "express": "^4.17.1",
      "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
      "pg": "^8.4.0",
      "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.10",
      "typeorm": "0.2.29",
      "validate.js": "^0.13.1"
   },
   "devDependencies": {
      "@types/bcrypt": "^3.0.0",
      "@types/express": "^4.17.9",
      "@types/node": "^14.14.8",
      "ts-node": "3.3.0",
      "ts-node-dev": "^1.0.0",
      "typescript": "^4.0.5"
   },
   "engines": {
      "node": "^14"
   }
}
```

and my **tsconfig.json**

```
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "outDir": "dist",
        "strict": true,
        "lib": ["es2017"],
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "incremental": false,
        "paths": {
            "*": ["node_modules/*"],
            "business/*": ["src/business"],
            "technical/*": ["src/technical"]
        }
    },
    "include": [
        "./**/*",
        "../common/**/*"
    ]
}
```

**ormconfig.ts**

```
import { ConnectionOptions } from 'typeorm';
import path from 'path';

const HOST : string = process.env.DB_HOST || "localhost";
const PORT : number =  Number(process.env.DB_PORT) || 5432;
const USER_NAME : string = process.env.DB_USERNAME || "test";
const PASSWORD : string = process.env.DB_PASSWORD || "test";
const DATABASE : string = process.env.DB_NAME || "test";

const fileBaseName : string = path.basename(__filename);
const fileExtention : string = path.extname(fileBaseName);

const ORMConfig = {
   type: "postgres",
   host: HOST,
   port: PORT,
   username: USER_NAME,
   password: PASSWORD,
   database: DATABASE,
   synchronize: true,
   logging: false,
   entities: [
      `src/business/**/*.entity${fileExtention}`
   ],
   migrations: [
      `src/migration/**/*${fileExtention}`
   ]
} as ConnectionOptions;

module.exports = ORMConfig;
```

my project structure

```
.
├── dist // contains my compiled js files
├── docker
│   ├── database.env
│   └── docker-compose.yaml
├── ormconfig.ts // where my connection options are living
├── package.json
├── README.md
├── src
|   ...
│   ├── index.ts
│   └── technical
|       ...
│       ├── typeorm
│       │   ├── connexion.ts
│       │   └── repository
│       │       └── createGetRepository.ts
│       ...
├── tsconfig.json
├── yarn-error.log
└── yarn.lock
```

Thanks,

Maxime

Comment: This is really weird, as the *dist/server/index.js* file you've shown does not contain an `import` statement. Your tsconfig (with `"module": "commonjs"`) looks fine (although for node 14 I'd recommend a more modern target than ES5). How did you start node? Maybe there just was a hiccup and you need to try again.

Comment: Hello, i started node with both `node dist/server/src/index.js` and  `node --input-type=module dist/server/src/index.js ` but none of thse command works. I aslo changed the target property of my tsconfig.json file from es5 to es2020 but i keep getting this error. I don't really know what is going on..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some research i finally figured out what was going wrong :

I was trying to launch my compiled js code with `node dist/src/index.js` witouth suspecting about the correct location of the ormconfig file (was it the one in dist/ folder, or the other one in the root of my project that was going to be involved?)

To retrieve my connection options in my `dist/src/technical/typeorm/connexion.js` file i was thinking that typeorm would search in the ormConfig.js file in the root of my **dist** folder.

Then i read this commented lines in the [ConnectionOptionReader](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/a7acb6b021b06541f150cb635fb96f5df67991c2/src/connection/ConnectionOptionsReader.ts#L12) class from the typeOrm github repository :

```
    constructor(protected options?: {
        /**
         * Directory where ormconfig should be read from.
         * By default its your application root (where your app package.json is located).
         */
        root?: string,
```

at this point, typeOrm would try to read connection options from the wrong ormconfig.ts file (the one located in the **root** of my project and also my development environment where all my code is using import statements) and that whas the source of the error.

May this explanation help someone who would make the same mistake in the future.